# Como detectar se a string digitada tem mais de 6 caracteres?

Tags: python-3.x, lógica

> Como faço pra detectar que a string digitada pelo usuário possui mais de 6 caracteres por exemplo???

.
.
.
.
.
..

.

Comment: Aonde isso foi digitado Marcos? Pode colocar o código que requisita essa informação?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

apenas use len(string)>6, a função len te retorna o tamanho da string ai é só comparar com o numero que quiser

Answer (score 2):

Você pode fazer [assim](https://repl.it/repls/DarkmagentaHumblePackage):

```
senha = '123Mudar'   # variável com a senha
tamanho = len(senha) # calcular o tamanho da senha com a função len
if tamanho > 6:      # verificar se a senha é maior que 6
  print("Senha maior que 6")
```